# How to Create a Modular Blazor Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am currently using ExtCore to build a modular API and I want to make the Blazor SPA application Modular too.

I want to have a core Blazor project which imports the .cshtml files from other projects so that I have a single project per section of the SPA application coding the solution in a modular way.

I can't use ExtCore as it required the project to be .net core and Blazor is .net standard (tried changing it to .net core and it blew up).

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor

Comment: Did you mean frontend SPA?

Comment: Sorry I meant backend in the business sense in terms of an administration system rather than the technology stack. I can see how that may have been confusing...

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: All you need is .cshtml files from other projects or something higher

Comment: just add your namespace to_ViewImports.cshtml and add the project to the Dependancies. Or do you want to do something on the runtime.

Comment: I did try that...

If the project is called Test.MyProject

I tried adding:

@using Test.MyProject

and

Test.MyProject.Pages

But I just get the red squiggly of doom

Comment: What about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since asking my question a lot has changed. Blazor is now a fully supported part of .net core and the tooling has massively improved.

**Creating a modular Blazor app is now made easier through Razor class libraries**

Razor Class Libraries allow you to create a project which contains

- Static Assets (css, js etc)
- Components
- Blazor Pages (see below on how to make them work in a modular way)

[Microsoft Docs: Razor class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

**Making Razor Class Libraries Modular**

Inside App.razor is the router for Blazor.

The router has a baked in parameter that takes an array of additional assemblies to look at and find any additional routes. Cleverly named **AdditionalAssemblies**

So you can use the "AdditionalAssemblies" parameter to point to a method which scans the referenced Razor Class Libraries for Pages.

```
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="AssemblyScanning.GetAssemblies().ToArray()">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

**Example Project**

I have put together an example project on github as an example.

[Github : ModularBlazor](https://github.com/treefishuk/ModularBlazor/tree/master)

No framework. Just the default Blazor bits, a couple of basic interfaces and some assembly scanning.

Comment: It seems to me that your project is missing a ModularBlazor.Components project (ModuleOne and ModuleTwo is referencing this). It does not have a .sln file either. Does it work for you if you download it (not pull latest, but download as zip) and run it? In addition to this. If you actually try to make it do something more than just loading the views, they won't. Try putting the functionality from the Click Me demo into your views. They won't update the value when clicking the button.

Comment: Good spot @Bjørn! My Apologies. I have now added the missing .sln and the Components project that was referenced but not included.

Comment: Awesome, still, if you add the demo counter feature that's present in the default blazor demo, it does not increase the count.. Do you know why?

Comment: @Bjørn I have updated the demo project again. The Counter has now been moved into the Components project and both Module one and Two render the Counter control successfully. Issue was with missing _Imports.razor files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ClassLibrary (.Net Standard). 
Modify the csproj by unloading it in Visual Studio. It must look similar to this.

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BlazorLinkOnBuild>False</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RunCommand>dotnet</RunCommand>
    <RunArguments>blazor serve</RunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.0-preview2-30230" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser" Version="0.1.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="0.1.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli" Version="0.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Pages\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Create a folder structure as below.

```
Pages
 |-----> _ViewImports.cshtml 
 | 
 |-----> Shared.cshtml
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Layouts
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Routing
@using MyLibrary
```

Shared.cshtml

```
@page "/shared"
<h1>This is a shared page</h1>
@functions {

}
```

*Build the MyLibrary.dll by right click on the project and Rebuild, There is a bug at this moment, this is not auto compiled with main project.*

Select the main web application and add the MyLibrary to the dependancies.

In the _ViewImports.cshtml of the main web app add the using directives.

```
@addTagHelper *, MyLibrary

@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Layouts
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Routing
@using WebApplication7
@using WebApplication7.Shared
@using MyLibrary.Pages
```

Now its time to add the link to the page

```
<NavLink href="/shared">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Shared Page
</NavLink>
```

More information
On Razor : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/01/asp-net-core-2-1-razor-ui-in-class-libraries/

On Blazor Issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/340

Comment: Definitely looks like it should do the job. However I get :

"Router' cannot find any component with a route for /shared" logged in the console

Comment: Did you compile the dll before add as dependancy  to the  main project, this is tried and tested code by myself.

Comment: Please share some more info about your problem.

Comment: I created an example project on github. If you want to check it over and tell me where I am going wrong that would be great: https://github.com/treefishuk/Modular-Blazor

Comment: @JonRyan, You have to mention whether my solution is working or not, I have shared a git hub repo.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your example does indeed seem to to the job. Thanks for helping to crack this @VibeeshanRC

Comment: @VibeeshanRC @JonRyan You cannot have `@page` components from external libraries yet. That's not implemented yet. You can have a `Shared` components that you can then use from your pages. more info https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/463